# How do I find the conditional probability of drawing two hands where the second hand is a four of a kind given that the first hand is a straight

Tags: combinatorics

Consider a standard 52-card deck. Suppose two hands (5 cards each, 10
cards in total) are randomly drawn (without replacement) from the deck.

Find the probability that the second hand is a four of a kind given that
the first hand is a straight (one of A-2-3-4-5, 2-3-4-5-6, ..., 10-J-Q-K-A; 10 cases
when suits are ignored)

Let's define $x$ = second hand is a 4 of a kind, and $y$ = first hand is a straight

So my intuition was that we are finding $P(x|y)$ so this is conditional probability. I can't understand how to use the formula:

$$\frac{{P(x \cap y)}}{P(y)}
$$

How would I solve for $P(x \cap y)$?

Comment: Without loss of generality, you can assume that the first hand is specifically Ace, deuce, three, four, five.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint*

There is a tendency to get tightly attached to some formula or other, and after that forego all thought.

For conditional probability problems, for example, often it is expedient to consider a reduced sample space rather than use *the* formula.

After drawing a straight, $5$ denominations will be missing a card, so you can't get four-of-a-kind from them.

Can you now work out the probability of getting four-of-a-kind from the *reduced* sample space ? That's all !

Comment: so the sample space would be C(47,5) since we are now choosing from a deck of 5 less cards, for the straights, now there is (13-5) or 8 face cards to choose from, as any of the 5 picked before cannot be used, and the last card can be any 1 of the remaining 43 cards?

Comment: Yes, that's it.